# unfamiliar python syntax on list initialization

Tags: python, list, syntax, list-initialization

Could someone please tell me what the statement in the 2nd line is doing? I cant find a similar example online. I think it is initializing Lst, but i cant quite picture what the list Lst will look like. Thanks

```
Lst = []
Lst = [ [] for i in range(65536)]
```

Answer (score 3):

What’s happening here is that it’s creating a list of lists. However, the inner lists will all be empty and the outer list that contains the empty list will be of size 65536.

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent

```
Lst = []
for i in range(65536):
    Lst.append( [] )
```

Answer (score 1):

it creates a list of 65536 '[]'